# How can I convert any video to h264 format?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video with a specific name which is the date when it is written. I don't really care about the name I want to convert it to this format then delete it. So one video gets in the file I convert it then remove the old one and move the new one to different file. The folder will always be empty or only contains 1 video. I'm using Windows 10.

For example,

```
ffmpeg -i *.mp4 -an -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 Todifferentfile/output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on FFMPEG and your input files being in the same folder.

- Within that folder make a new folder `converted`
- Paste the below text into a `bat` file. (save into FFMPEG folder)
  (Basically open notepad and paste - Change save filter to 'all files'
  and give it a `bat` extension)

BAT file script:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -an "converted\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

Make sure you save the output files into a different path to prevent overwrite (in above example 'converted' folder).

Basically it will process all `*.mp4` files within that folder (using `%%a` for filename).

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG requires exact filename without wildcards.
You need to create a batch script that list files based on wildcards and calls ffmpeg with exact filename for each.